# How to get contents of element as a parameter to function call on click event in Vue

Tags: vuejs2

I want to be able to do the equivalent of this in Vue:

```
<span onclick="somefunc(this.innerText)">blah</span>
```

When I try this in Vue, I don't get the inner text of the span:

```
<span @click="somefunc(this.innerText)">blah</span>
```

**this** equates to something else in Vue and it seems to vary. Sometimes its the event object and sometimes its a Vue object.

How do I get at the innerText every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I just switched to normal javascript and ignored the Vue approach.

somefunc had to be declared outside of the Vue methods to work:

```
<span onclick="somefunc(this.innerText)">blah</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue to achive what you asked, you should do something like this :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const innerText = 'blah';
function somefunc(sometext:string):void {
...
}
</script>

<template>
   <span @click="somefunc(innerText)">{{innerText}}</span>
</template>
```

Comment: yes that'll work, but it's not what I'm looking for as the inner text changes depending on the language of the user and I want a generic function that will work in every case of this

Comment: Is the translated inner text static generated by some backend like php ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue 2 and Options Api this might help you

```
<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      textVal: "some text"
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
<span @click="funcEx(textVal)">{{textVal}}</span>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**